# strange issue with FLASH/PHP

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

i am having strange issue with Flash and PHP. actually i have one Forgot password form in flash in which user enters his email id and when presses submit button flash passes data to PHP and **retrieves**(here i am stuck) data from PHP.

The issue is Flash getting **UNDEFINED** from PHP.

**my flash code.**

```
var email_id:RegExp = /(\w|[_.\-])+@((\w|-)+\.)+\w{2,4}+/;
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("forgot_password.php");
var urlVariable:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);


btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_submit_click);
function btn_submit_click(e:Event)
{
    if(txt_email.text == "")
    {
        txt_error.text = "Email can not be blank.";
    }
    else if(!email_id.test(txt_email.text))
    {
        txt_error.text = "Enter proper email address.";
    }
    else
    {
        urlVariable.mailId = txt_email.text;
        urlRequest.data = urlVariable;

        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
    }
}

function urlLoader_complete(e:Event)
{
        trace(e.target.data.return_var); // **it receive Undefined** i am checking in flashlog.txt :(
    //txt_error.text = e.target.data.return_var;
}
```

**my PHP code**

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

$query = "select * from user_account where email='".$_REQUEST['mailId']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo "return_var=success";
}
else
{
    echo "return_var=failed";
}
 ?>
```

**there is a space before return_var but i don't know why.. i have checked my PHP file 100 times it is perfect than what is the issue??????????????????????????????????????????**

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
If i am tracing

    trace(e.target.data);

it traces 
   %20return%5Fvar=success
```

Note %20 before return%5var // what is that?????????????

Comment: I dont a see an obvious issue, but in any case you should also do a server side validation, cause its really easy for someone to post your forms with invalid emails

Comment: Your return value from the server is a "STRING" parse it as a string and not an object. If you want to pass an object from the server use JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all thank you all for your contributions.

Now the issue was not related with Flash or PHP but it was related with our server. if i am creating PHP file and directly saving on our server than that PHP file gives response with adding one space before variable name. and if i am creating PHP file and saving it in my local drive and than pasting it on my server it works perfectly!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

see the response difference between two files..............

```
return_var=success

 return_var=success // adding space before response.
```

may be its issue related with memory but now its working fine so cheers!!!!!!!!!

Again many Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously problem isn't in PHP, anyway you should write it something like this to prevent SQL injection...

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$email = $_GET['mailId'];
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

$query = "SELECT email FROM user_account WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)? 'return_var=success': 'return_var=failed';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

and change your `urlLoader_complete()` function to:

```
function urlLoader_complete(e:Event)
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);  
    var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);  
    trace(vars.return_var);
}
```

does that help?

Comment: Thanx for the answer. but issue is different pls check edits.